# What are these extra bytes in my binary file?

Tags: c, gcc, operating-system, kernel

I am in the process of writing a small operating system in C. I have written a bootloader and I'm now trying to get a simple C file (the "kernel") to compile with `gcc`:

```c
int main(void) { return 0; }
```

I compile the file with the following command:

```
gcc kernel.c -o kernel.o -nostdlib -nostartfiles
```

I use the linker to create the final image using this command:

```
ld kernel.o -o kernel.bin -T linker.ld --oformat=binary
```

The contents of the `linker.ld` file are as follows:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7e00;

    .text ALIGN (0x00) :
    {
        *(.text)
    }
}
```

(The bootloader loads the image at address `0x7e00`.)

This seems to work quite well - `ld` produces a 128-byte file containing the following instructions in the first 11 bytes:

```
00000000 55                             push    ebp
00000001 48                             dec eax
00000002 89 E5                          mov ebp, esp
00000004 B8 00 00 00 00                 mov eax, 0x00000000
00000009 5D                             pop ebp
0000000A C3                             ret
```

However, I can't figure out what the other 117 bytes are for. Disassembling them seems to produce a bunch of garbage that doesn't make any sense. The existence of the additional bytes has me wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Should I be concerned?

[image: hexdump of the file]

Comment: Oh, and yes, I do realize the code generated needs to run in protected mode. The bootloader will take care of switching the CPU to protected mode.

Comment: @Aftnix: I'm generating a flat binary file. There should be no ELF header.

Comment: How about after: strip --strip-all -R .note -R .comment kernel.bin

Comment: Perhaps that's debugging information? Try something like:
ld kernel.o -o --strip-all kernel.bin -T linker.ld --oformat=binary

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are additional sections, which were not stripped and not discarded. You want your `linker.ld` file to look like this:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7e00;

    .text ALIGN (0x00) :
    {
        *(.text)
    }

    /DISCARD/ :
    {
        *(.comment)
        *(.eh_frame_hdr)
        *(.eh_frame)
    }
}
```

I know what sections to discard from the output of `objdump -t kernel.o`.

Answer (score -1):

Simple, you're using gcc, and it always put its initialization code before passing control to your main.
What's on that start up code I don't know, but they are there. As you may see there's also an comment 'GNU' on your binary, you can't print specific sectors by using objdump -s -j 'section name'.